# XML files to be sum up

Tags: python, .net, xml, xslt, ado.net

I have 10 XML files containing several Objects.
The XML files define ACTIONS on those objects.

ACTIONS on objects=

- MODIFY values
- DELETE Object
- CREATE Object with values

I need to get the result of those 10 XML files (10 files of actions on those objects).

Any suggestion ?

- programming .NET and ADO ?
- programming PYTHON and minidom ?
- spyXML from Altova ?
- a commercial tool to load MYSQL ?

Comment: The question should be: for what purpose are you writing it? Does it need to be integrated in an existing system? If it's just a project and you just need the results, just choose any language and XML library you wish. Based on the information you've given, I'd say a basic Python script should do the trick.

Comment: Anytime I need to do any XML processing, I use Saxon (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) and XSLT/XQuery.

Comment: @DevNull: Whereas any time I need to do any XML processing, I use LINQ to XML... :)

Comment: I only need the output. The script or executable will be run 1 or 2 times per day

Comment: If using PYTHON, which library would you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we have used SAXON + XSLT2.0 (saxon called from Perl) and Perl::Twig for the parts we did not know how to program in XSLT

Comment: We should have better use Python with native XML libraries.
We used Perl with twigxml though (now project is over)